# How to build multi array in Transformer Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have the following code:

```
public function transform($obj)
{
    return [
        'id'     => (int) $obj->id,
        'name' => $obj->name,
        "prototype" => $obj->_prototypes()->get()
    ];
}
```

Where `$obj->_prototypes()->get()` is collection with fields `(id, name)`.

How to format new array like as:

```
'name' =>  'name' => $obj->name,
"prototype" => [
    ["id": 1, "name" : "ok"],
     ["id": 2, "name" : "ok 2"],
]
```

So, I need to iterate `$obj->_prototypes()->get()` inside transformer object.

So, I have nested objects(relations). And now I need to use loop, that to take nested object and combine them to one output object again.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a for each loop, and in the for each loop use array_push or array_merge to merge the current iteration of the loop into a new array.

array_push docs = http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

array_merge docs = http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

Definitely take a look at fractal's transformers. There are really nice features, including yours: http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/

```
class MyTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public $defaultIncludes = ['prototype'];

    public function transform($obj) 
    {
         return [
             'id'   => (int) $obj->id,
             'name' => $obj->name
         ]
    }

    public function includePrototype($obj)
    {
         return $this->collection($obj->_prototypes()->get(), new PrototypeTransformer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but  it does not work when I try to transform object inside transformed object

Comment: @Gagamerov I updated my answer with a code snippet. Is this what are you looking for?